# There was an ERROR in the SQLite Database file please tell me how to rectify it

Tags: java, android, sqlite

There was an ERROR in the SQLite Database file when i'm Run This project the application was forcely closed and indicate the ERROR in the line number 36 please tell me how to rectify it .....
        enter code here
        package com.flocater;

```
    import com.flocator.R;`enter code here`
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class Friendfinderactivity extends Activity {
        /** C`

    `alled when the activity is first created. */
        String deviceid = "";


        String device_id = "";
        String user_id = "";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from"
                    + DBHelper.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME, null);

            int rows = cursor.getCount();

            if (rows > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                user_id = cursor.getString(0);
                device_id = cursor.getString(3);
            }
            db.close();
            if (device_id.equals(deviceid)) {
                setContentView(R.layout.subscriber);
            } else
                setContentView(R.layout.subscribe);
        }

        public void subscribeUser(View v) {
            // get access to views
            EditText editName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editName);
            EditText editPhone = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
            EditText editArea = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editArea);
            EditText editCity = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editCity);

            boolean done = DBHelper.AddFriends(this, editName.getText().toString(),
                    editPhone.getText().toString(), deviceid, editArea.getText()
                            .toString(), editCity.getText().toString());

            if(done) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Subscribed Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Friendfinderactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Could not subscribe!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void addFriends(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddFriends.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void viewFriends(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SeeFriends.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void seeLocation(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SeeFriends.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void updateDetails(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,UpdateFriends.class);
            intent.putExtra("userid", user_id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

ERROR MESSAGE :
05-20 02:04:45.380: E/SQLiteLog(1851): (1) near "fromnull": syntax error
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Process: com.flocator, PID: 1851
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flocator/com.flocater.Friendfinderactivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "fromnull": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * fromnull
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "fromnull": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * fromnull
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.flocater.Friendfinderactivity.onCreate(Friendfinderactivity.java:37)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-20 02:04:45.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Check `SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME!=null` in `DBHelper`

Comment: *while compiling: select * fromnull* - you need a table name and please change `select * from` to `select * from ' with a space

Comment: Your logcat cleary said `(1) near "fromnull": syntax error`. `Do you know why logcat is there?`

Answer (score 3):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from"
                    + DBHelper.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME, null);
```

Problem 1: Add a space behind from and "

Problem 2: Your DBHelper.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME seems to resolve to null

Comment: ya i tried your given solution but it didn't workout the same error was occur , so please tell me another solution to rectify it...

Comment: Is this correct ?? :                                                                                                   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DBHelper.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME,null);

Comment: Yes, it should work but your 'DBHelper.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME' probably still returns 'null'

Comment: Hi i'm Surendran prabhakaran my app is not working yar please give your email id i send my app and after that please rectify my error ...